# how can i pass this intent data into Android correctly

Tags: android, video, android-intent

Activity 2

```
         public class Menus extends Activity {
//set constants for MediaStore to query, and show videos
private final static Uri MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI = MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
private final static String _ID = MediaStore.Video.Media._ID;
private final static String MEDIA_DATA = MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA;
//flag for which one is used for images selection
private GridView _gallery; 
private Cursor _cursor;
private int _columnIndex;
private int[] _videosId;
private Uri _contentUri;


protected Context _context;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    _context = getApplicationContext();
    _gallery = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.videoGrdVw);
    //set default as external/sdcard uri
    _contentUri = MEDIA_EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    //initialize the videos uri 
    //showToast(_contentUri.getPath());
    initVideosId();
    //set gallery adapter
    setGalleryAdapter();
}
private void setGalleryAdapter() {
    _gallery.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(_context));
    _gallery.setOnItemClickListener(_itemClickLis);

}
private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener _itemClickLis = new OnItemClickListener() 
{
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) 
    {
        // Now we want to actually get the data location of the file
        String [] proj={MEDIA_DATA};
        // We request our cursor again
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        // We want to get the column index for the data uri
        int count = _cursor.getCount();
        //
        _cursor.moveToFirst();
        //
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(MEDIA_DATA);
        // Lets move to the selected item in the cursor
        _cursor.moveToPosition(position);

        Intent data = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Editor.class); data.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID); startActivity(data);
    }
};
private void initVideosId() {
    try
    {
        //Here we set up a string array of the thumbnail ID column we want to get back
        String [] proj={_ID};
        // Now we create the cursor pointing to the external thumbnail store
        _cursor = managedQuery(_contentUri,
                proj, // Which columns to return
                null,       // WHERE clause; which rows to return (all rows)
                null,       // WHERE clause selection arguments (none)
                null); // Order-by clause (ascending by name)
        int count= _cursor.getCount();
        // We now get the column index of the thumbnail id
        _columnIndex = _cursor.getColumnIndex(_ID);
        //initialize 
        _videosId = new int[count];
        //move position to first element
        _cursor.moveToFirst();          
        for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
        {           
            int id = _cursor.getInt(_columnIndex);
            //
            _videosId[i]= id;
            //
            _cursor.moveToNext();
            //
        }
    }catch(Exception ex)
    {

    }

}


//
private class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
    public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context c) 
    {
        _context = c;
    }
    public int getCount() 
    {
        return _videosId.length;
    }
    public Object getItem(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        ImageView imgVw= new ImageView(_context);;
        try
        {
            if(convertView!=null)
            {
                imgVw= (ImageView) convertView;
            }
            imgVw.setImageBitmap(getImage(_videosId[position]));
            imgVw.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(96, 96));
            imgVw.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("StartActivity:getView()-135: ex " + ex.getClass() +", "+ ex.getMessage());
        }
        return imgVw;
    }

    // Create the thumbnail on the fly
    private Bitmap getImage(int id) {
        Bitmap thumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(
                getContentResolver(),
                id, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, null);
        return thumb;
    }

}
```

}

Activity 3

```
       public class Editor extends Activity {

private VideoView video;
private MediaController ctlr;
ImageButton video1;
int isClicked = 0;
ImageButton audio;
int isClicked1 = 0;
int data = getIntent(data).getExtras() 
    .getInt("mnt/sdcard-ext"); 

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    setContentView(R.layout.editor);


    video1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.video);
    video1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isClicked == 0) {
                video1.setImageResource(R.drawable.video_pressed);
                isClicked = 1;
            } else {
                video1.setImageResource(R.drawable.video1);
                isClicked = 0;
            }
          }
     });

    audio = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.audio);
    audio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isClicked1 == 0) {
                audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio_pressed);
                isClicked1 = 1;
            } else {
                audio.setImageResource(R.drawable.audio);
                isClicked1 = 0;
            }
        }
      });

    if (clip.exists()) {
          video=(VideoView)findViewById(R.id.video);
          video.setVideoPath(clip.getAbsolutePath());

     ctlr=new MediaController(this);
     ctlr.setMediaPlayer(video);
     video.setMediaController(ctlr);
     video.requestFocus();
     video.start();
    }
  }
 }
```

I am never gonna be a programmer i'm just trying to pass this class. So don't worry. I need to know how to pass this intent data through to the third activity, but i'm not sure where to put the Extras and get extras.

Android Manifest

```
              <activity 
      android:name=".Editor"
      android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
       <intent-filter>
      <action 
  android:name="com.ave.Editor" />
      <category 
  android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
```

If you need anymore information let me know. I'm tried of messing with this confusing crap. And any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 Intent data = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Editor.class); data.putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID); startActivity(data);
```

I find it to be easier to expand this.

```
Intent i=new Intent(this, Editor.class);
i.putExtra("data1", _ID);
startActivity(data);
```

In the other Activity:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
{
    //===setting content view, any other setup you wanna do
    Intent i=getIntent();
    String data=i.getStringExtra("data1");

    if(data!=null)
        //do something with it
    else
        //the data is null; don't do anything with it or you'll get a NullPointerException
}
```

I think this is what you wanna do. If not, tell me!

Comment: You're close. Just tried its and i am grateful for you help but its not how i need it to be passed. I'll just try to explain it better.  Activity 2 displays all video thumbnails in a VideoGridView from the SD card of the phone. Anyways, In activity 2 on clicking a thumbnail i want it to be passed and viewed within the videoView of the 3rd activity. Not necessarily autoplayed but visible and if clicking on the screen you could play it. I can probably figure that out myself, But all help you can give me thank you! This is due monday and i'm stressing out.

Comment: When the user clicks on a thumbnail, just send the path of the file as the extra. When Activity 3 gets the path, it should load the file from the path and display that in the VideoView. Then you could use the VideoView.setPath() or .setURI() to load it and then immediately use .pause() to pause it if it tries to autoplay. I suppose you could send the video with the putExtra(Serializable, String) and getSerializableExtra(String) methods.

Comment: Hope your project goes over well!

Answer (score 0):

The line `int data = getIntent(data).getExtras()
    .getInt("mnt/sdcard-ext");` in Activity 3 should probably be moved to the onCreate() method.
Also, when you do `putExtra("mnt/sdcard-ext", _ID)` and `getInt`, instead of `"mnt/sdcard-ext"`, you should probably use a package name such as `com.example.appname.extraname`, as referred to here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html